# How to allow to read logs by pod only from itself?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have following RBAC:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: stdout-log-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: stdout-log-reader-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: stdout-log-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment
spec:
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sa
```

What I want to achieve is: be able to view logs by pod itself (via curl & k8s api). And it works, but I want to restrict permissions that given pod will be able to see only logs from itself. With above configuration it will see logs from all resources in namespace it is deployed (default in this case).

Comment: I created the same `role` and tested it with [`kubectl auth can-i`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access), `sa` can't see logs from services or deployments e.g. How did you test it? + Which kubernetes version is used?